# need to create a mongoose transaction wrapper which will pass session as parameter to functions that actually do query operations to create or update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions, es6-promise

So lets say i have a function that takes care of user creation which was previously available to us. Now we just want the function to work in the form of one transaction that creates all users together if success or fails completely when it encounters any error. I am assuming passing just the session to the existing function from the transaction wrapper should take care of this. Any number of such function can be passed together and the wrapper should handle them all as a single transaction.

```
 const createUsers = async (users = []) => {
  try {
    return UserModel.create(users).then((res) => {
      logger.info(`[Start-Up] Created ${res.length} users`);
    }, (rej) => {
      logger.error(`[Start-Up] Failed to create users - ${rej}`);
      throw new Error(rej);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('Failed to create Users', err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-transactions

---

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

```
const createUsers = async (users = []) => {
  const session = await UserModel.startSession();
  try {
    await session.withTransaction(() => {
        return UserModel.create(users, { session: session }).then((res) => {
          logger.info(`[Start-Up] Created ${res.length} users`);
        }, (rej) => {
          logger.error(`[Start-Up] Failed to create users - ${rej}`);
          throw new Error(rej);
        });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('Failed to create Users', err);
  } finally {
     session.endSession();
  }
};
```

Comment: I was expecting the session portion to be handled separately in a wrapper. that way we can pass as many functions like the one above and based on the success of every query the total transaction becomes true

Comment: @RajibKumarDey https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-transactions